Python - Creating a string through large numbers of String Concatenation - What method should be used?
Firstly - Currently working with Python 3.12
I'm working on a process that reads through a large body of text (character by character) and creates a string from characters selected under specific conditions. The process I've taken is to declare an empty string and then iterate over the text (using a simple for loop) and concatenate when the character is to be used.
For illustration, I'll let the body of text be a single string (body_of_text), i.e.
final_text : str = ""

for index in range(body_of_text):
  if use_character(body_of_text[index]):
       str += body_of_text[index]


The question I have is whether this is computationally inefficient? and if so, is there a better approach in Python?. I ask as with Strings being immutable in Python that every time I call the Concatenation that (in my understanding - please correct if wrong) I'm creating a temporary String object with value str + body_of_text[index], destroying the previous str object, and then creating a new String object str with the value of the temporary String object. Given that the addition the the str at each selection through use_character()  is a mere character, this seems to be a lot of computational work to repeat extensively (I'm processing a VERY large text corpora)
Is my reasoning here correct? and if so, what other methods should be used? A basic thought was to create an ordered list that I add each selected character to and then at the end of processing body_of_text that I use the join() method.
Any insights and/or corrections to my interpretation would be greatly appreciated!

Related: Python string 'join' is faster (?) than '+', but what's wrong here?

It's also worth seeing Slower string concatenation in CPython 3.11 to see in practice what Alex was warning about in his answer - it might seem that += is sometimes faster, but it is gonna bite you in the hand some day and the ''.join() should be a way to go, which is even stated in documentation: "(...) str.join() or io.StringIO can be used to efficiently construct strings from multiple fragments."

I'd use final_text = "".join(filter(use_character, body_of_text))

@Swifty - I'm almost brand new to Python so was unfamiliar with filter when posting. Just read into it - Yes, will use. Many thanks!!!

You're welcome; though I didn't dig into the efficiency of this method (and so I don't have enough material to write a good enough answer), I believe the use of filter and join to be quite efficient.
